# Определить местоположение пользователя по примеру сайта

Tags: javascript, yandex-maps-api, yandex-maps-jsapi, yandexmapkit

Хочу сделать реализацию местоположения пользователя по примеру сайта lamoda.ru То есть, чтобы при клике на кнопку, высвечивалось местоположение. Какой метод будет наиболее оптимальным?

Comment: 1.узнаете геолокацию, через апи браузера или публичный сервис который определяет по ip, 2.рисуете точку на карте

Comment: Пытаюсь через api yandex.maps сделать, но мне не на карте нужна отрисовка, а в тексте.

Comment: Это называется обратное геокодирование, https://tech.yandex.ru/maps/geocoder/doc/desc/concepts/input_params-docpage/

Comment: Я вам очень благодарен за то, что отвечаете на вопросы новичка, но наверное не совсем чётко объяснил задачу, либо сам не понимаю: есть необходимость, чтобы пользователь, зайдя на страницу, мог кликнуть на кнопку и тогда в форме поиска городов на этой странице, отобразится его текущее местоположение.

Comment: Огромное спасибо, буду разбираться

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вот, примерно так можно воспользоваться одним из множества публичных сервисов:

```js
fetch('http://ipinfo.io/json').then(r => r.json()).then(r => {
  loc.innerHTML = JSON.stringify(r, 0, '<br>');
})
```

```html
<div id=loc></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 public getGeoLocation(): Observable<Position> {
        return new Observable((observer: Observer<Position>) => {
            if (navigator.geolocation) {
                navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition((pos) => {
                    const position: Position = {
                        latitude: pos.coords.latitude,
                        longitude: pos.coords.longitude,
                    };
                    this._zone.run(() => observer.next(position));
                    this.geoPosition.next(position);
                });
            } else {
                this._zone.run(() => observer.error(null));
                this.geoPosition.next(null);
            }
        });
    }
```

Comment: Пожалуйста, дайте более развёрнутый ответ. Допполнить ответ вы можете кнопкой [править](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/posts/1052460/edit).